# Call a file in another folder in Eclipse for Python project

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-neon

I have a small enough Python project in Eclipse Neon and keep getting the same error and can't find proper documentation on how to solve.  In my main I need to call a file that is located in another folder.  The error I receive is IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

I have an empty **init**.py file in the folder (XML_TXT) that I'm trying to use.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is test.txt in the folder structure?

Comment: It is in the XML_TXT folder

Comment: One more question - that image of the code snippet that shows line 12 to 16, which file is that from?

Comment: That is from my Main.py file.  So, in Main.py in my u = Groovy("test.txt") while test.txt is in the XML_TXT folder.

Comment: Okay, I've edited my answer to add another solution which should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Groovy is importing okay, or else you would get an ImportError. An IOError indicates that it can't find "test.txt". Does that file exist?

It will work if the file path is relative to where you are running the script from. So for example if test.txt is in a folder

```
Groovy("folder_name/test.txt")
```

You can also go up in the directory structure if you need to, for example

```
Groovy("../folder_name/test.txt")
```

Or, if you want to be able to run the file from anywhere, you can have python work out the absolute path of the file for you.

```
import os

filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'folder_name/test.txt')
u = Groovy(filename)
```

Comment: Yes, the file does exist.  I previously tried your first solution and just the other and it did not work.

Comment: Okay, try printing out your current working directory  by adding print(os.getcwd()) above the call to Groovy. (You will also need to import os at the top). Then work out the path from the cwd to the test.txt file

Comment: Still getting the same error and tried a variety of paths to get me there.

Comment: Why am I getting the double slashes???  This seems to get me a bit closer.

Comment: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'H:\\XMLConverter\\XML_TXT\\MVM.txt'

Comment: @PaulPearson Double slashes is a Windows thing - nothing to worry about. Is there a file at that location? (it's changed to MVM.txt from test.txt?)

Comment: Ah.  There is a file at that location, yes.  Sorry, yes it changed.  Both of those, really all, files are in the same folder.

Comment: Fixed it.  Friday.  Found a small error on my part.

Comment: @PaulPearson :-D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157160/discussion-between-paul-pearson-and-chasmani).